# how to validate Zipcode for US or Canada in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex

I want to know that is there any way to validate the the zipcode of US or Zipcode of Canada?I have tried to use regex.
Like for US

```
- (BOOL)validateZip:(NSString *)candidate {
    NSString *emailRegex = @"(^{5}(-{4})?$)|(^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][A-Z][- ]*[A-Z]$)";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 

    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];   
}
```

but it's not working.Please any body have any idea regarding this validation.if any rest api is there for the validation?Please guide me if possible?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11230585/529363)

Comment: **For Swift 3.0** click on the url http://stackoverflow.com/a/44038538/4402354

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the US, you have the quantifiers (`{5}`, `{4}`, `?`) correct but forgot to specify exactly what you're quantifying. You want:

```
(^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?$)
```

For Canada, according to Wikipedia, the format is `A0A 0A0`, so I would do:

```
(^[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z][- ]*[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]$)
```

Now, I'd write the complete expression like this, with case insensitivity enabled:

```
@"^(\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?|[a-z]\\d[a-z][- ]*\\d[a-z]\\d)$"
```

Frankly, I'm not actually familiar with Objective C or iOS, and sadly I haven't tested the above. However, previously I've seen such posts mention `NSRegularExpression`, which is missing in your code, but perhaps isn't necessary. Take a look at others' examples to see what other simple errors you might be making. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

We used this but its only for UK Postcodes. See @acheong87 answer to alter the regex to fit your criteria and other good answers.

```
NSString *postcodeRegex = @"[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]?([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}";//WITH SPACES
NSPredict *postcodeValidate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", postcodeRegex];

if ([postcodeValidate evaluateWithObject:postcodeField.text] == YES) {  
     NSLog (@"Postcode is Valid");  
} else {  
     NSLog (@"Postcode is Invalid");    
}
```

I advise you test the regex first using this great tool http://www.regexr.com

EDIT

Current regex does not support spaces in postcode after further testing. This will fix that issue.

```
NSString *postcodeRegex = @"[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]?(\s|)([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}";//WITH SPACES
```

Comment: I have used this on a commercial app and never heard of any issues so yes.

Comment: I entered M22<space>0XC, and it says invalid postal code

Comment: @magic your right I just tested this and it doesn't for some reason I thought it did. I have just updated my post with a new slightly adjusted expression. I hope that helps.