# Issue with NSRegularExpression / RegEx to validate Postal Code

Tags: ios, regex, validation, nsregularexpression

I have the following two methods, where I am calling an `NSRegularExpression` (first time using this) with two separate patterns, one to check against Canadian and the other American Postal/Zip codes.

```
-(BOOL)isValidPostalCode:(NSString*)code
{
    BOOL isValid = NO;
    NSString *cdnCheck = @"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z][- ]*\d[A-Z]\d$";
    NSString *usCheck  = @"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$";

    if ([self validateString:code withPattern:cdnCheck] || [self validateString:code withPattern:usCheck]) {
        isValid = YES;
    }

    return isValid;
}

- (BOOL)validateString:(NSString *)string withPattern:(NSString *)pattern
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't create regex with given string and options");
    }

    NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
    NSRange matchRange = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:textRange];
    NSTextCheckingResult *resultString = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:textRange];

    BOOL didValidate = NO;
    if (matchRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        didValidate = YES;
    }

    return didValidate;
}
```

In the second method, matchRange's length is always *0* (which I think is an indicator of no match?), and resultString is always *nil*... And I can't figure out why.

**What am I doing wrong?**

-- DISCLAIMERS --

a) I am passing a string - with no whitespaces - such as 'V6E1H8' or '90210', so those are valid candidates

b) Yes, I know those are redundant checks in the second method, I am just debugging with various other options from the [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html) and thought to leave it in there...

c) FYI, I got the expressions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230446/ios-valid-zip-code-check) (and a few more) and they check out on http://regexpal.com/, so I am assuming that the patterns themselves are valid, and it's an issue with my logic (I am admittedly a bit fuzzy on how NSRange works and how the NSRegEx (excuse the shorthand) evaluates a valid result...

Comment: I suspect all you need to do is double up all those backslashes.  Objective C string literals are similar to Java's; you have to escape backslashes if you want them to appear in the string.

Comment: Oh Jesus. I don't know how many times I read that in various tutorials over the past few hours and didn't even look at mine, assuming since I copied them from an accepted answer they were formatted properly.... WILL TEST!

Comment: @jesses.co.tt: Here is a [test](http://goo.gl/107wev), you must double the backslashes in Objective-C regex patterns with shorthand classes.